# Return to main function in python

Tags: python-3.x, function

Working on Python 3.4.3 
Let's say I have created three fuctions:

```
def choosing(mylist=[]):
    print("We will have to make a list of choices")
    appending(mylist)
    done = False
    while(done == "False"):
        confirm = input("Is your list complete?[Y/N]")
        if(confirm == "Y"):
            print("Yaay! Choices creation complete."
                  "{} choices have been added successfully".format(len(mylist)))
            done = True
        elif(confirm == "N"):
            action = input("What do you want to do? [Append/Delete]")
            if(action == "Append"):
                appending(mylist)
                done = False
            elif(action == "Delete"):
                removing(mylist)
                done = False

def appending(mylist1 = []):
    print("Please type EOF when you want to stop!")
    while True:
        c = input("Please enter EOF to stop adding. Please enter a choice: ")
        if(c=="EOF"):
            break
        else:
            mylist1.append(c)
    print("You have inserted {} choices".format(len(mylist1)))
    print("Please verify them below: ")
    for x in range(0, len(mylist1)):
        print(mylist1[x])

def removing(mylist2 = []):
    print("Following are choices: ")
    r = input("What do you want to remove? ")
    mylist2.remove(r)
    print("{} successfully removed!".format(r))
```

Now problem is I can't just call `choices()` in append or remove function as choices() function will call append again and again infinitely.
So how do I get back in choices after appending or removing data in list?

Comment: Put whatever is in `choices` into an infinite `while` loop.

Comment: Could you explain when and how `choices()` calls `append()` or `remove()`?

Comment: `def choices():`<br>`append(x)` ofcourse I have whole proper code formatted. @ASCIIThenANSI

Comment: @ASCIIThenANSI I have edited and put the whole code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by tobias_k, you should add the contents of `choices()` into a while loop.
I also found
some other problems:

- `False` does not equal `"False"`, so your `while` loop never runs.
- You use terms like `mylist`, `mylist1`, and `mylist2` - it's better to rename these to `choosing_list`, `appending_list`, and `removing_list`, so it's clearer.
- You also shouldn't use False to define a while loop - instead, make a variable, then set it to True. When you have to stop, set it to False.

Here is the code with those problems fixed:

```
def appending(appending_list = []):
    print("Please type EOF when you want to stop!")
    while True:
        c = input("Please enter EOF to stop adding. Please enter a choice: ")
        if(c=="EOF"):
            break
        else:
            appending_list.append(c)
    print("You have inserted {} choices".format(len(appending_list)))
    print("Please verify them below: ")
    for x in range(0, len(appending_list)):
        print(appending_list[x])
    return appending_list

def removing(removing_list = []):
    print("Following are choices: ")
    r = input("What do you want to remove? ")
    removing_list.remove(r)
    print("{} successfully removed!".format(r))
    return removing_list

print("We will have to make a list of choices")
choosing_list = appending()
list_incomplete = True
while list_incomplete:
    confirm = input("Is your list complete?[Y/N]")
    if(confirm == "Y"):
        print("Yaay! Choices creation complete."
              "{} choices have been added successfully".format(len(choosing_list)))
        list_incomplete = False
    elif(confirm == "N"):
        action = input("What do you want to do? [Append/Delete]")
        if(action == "Append"):
             choosing_list = appending(choosing_list)
        elif(action == "Delete"):
            choosing_list = removing(choosing_list)
```

Let me know if there's any problems with this code.

Comment: Really appreciate it! I am a beginner! Your code helped a lot to me! Thanks man